# Where should I place the code with roles in Yii framework?

Tags: yii, authorization

Here's the code I found in Yii framework manual:

```
$auth=Yii::app()->authManager;

$auth->createOperation('createPost','create a post');
$auth->createOperation('readPost','read a post');
$auth->createOperation('updatePost','update a post');
$auth->createOperation('deletePost','delete a post');

$bizRule='return Yii::app()->user->id==$params["post"]->authID;';
$task=$auth->createTask('updateOwnPost','update a post by author himself',$bizRule);
$task->addChild('updatePost');

$role=$auth->createRole('reader');
$role->addChild('readPost');

$role=$auth->createRole('author');
$role->addChild('reader');
$role->addChild('createPost');
$role->addChild('updateOwnPost');
```

and so on. 
The question is Where should I place the code for creating roles, tasks, etc?

Answer (score 1):

You should use this code in **protected/controllers/RbacController.php**

After modifing **protected/config/main.php**

```
return array(
'components'=>array(
    'db'=>array(
        'class'=>'CDbConnection',
        'connectionString'=>'sqlite:path/to/file.db',
    ),
    'authManager'=>array(
        'class'=>'CDbAuthManager',
        'connectionID'=>'db',
    ),
),
);
```

This is the official documentation:

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.auth#using-default-roles

Comment: That documentation states "Therefore, we only need to run the above code one time, and NOT for every request." - I would think that a separate console command might be a better place for code like that than a controller (and where in the controller would you suggest putting it?).

Comment: In a actionInit() for this code and then run the init command before other actions of the same controller. I agree with you that it a separate console command might be a better place. In this case give a look to this extension: http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/auth-init-command

Answer (score 1):

This took me awhile to understand, so let me answer your questions as I understand how yii works.

You will first create the appropriate tables following the sql code found in framework/web/auth

You can use phpmyadmin to populate the database

You can also create a controller in which you will run all of code above. That gets run once, because you are just populating a database

The controller can be called myInitController.php and stored with your other controllers.
The controller can be as simple as

```
<?php

class myInitController extends Controller
{
    public function actionRun()
    {    
        $auth=Yii::app()->authManager;
        $auth->createOperation('createPost','create a post');

        echo "this is it";
    }
}
```

Then you would run it by going to www.yourwebsite.com/myInit/Run
Verify what got written to the database. Don't push this controller to production. You don't want someone else running the command.

So your options are

1. hand enter data through something like phpmyadmin
2. create a customer controller which can store all of the php commands and execute
3. use gii to create models and CRUD functions (be careful of composite primary keys)

I hope this helps.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Clear. Detailed. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This piece of code will create the items in database. You have to execute it.

You can create an action in one of your controller and then run it.

> localhost/myAppName/myController/myAction

Or you can create a php file as well. Then juste paste your piece of code inside and run it.